# Why does my program display the null vector?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why my program displays the nul vector :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


template <class T>
std::vector<int> collect_values(const T & t, int first, int next_to_last) {
    std::vector<int> v(next_to_last-first);
    for(int i=0; i<next_to_last - first; i++) {
        v[i] = t(v[i]);
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    int a=0, b=5;
    auto square=[](int i) {return i*i;};
    std::vector<int> v;
    v = collect_values(square,a,b);
    for(int i=0; i<b-a; i++) {
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Okay, at the end of the loop the vector that will be in the function will be deleted. But I stored that function, so the vector should be stored, right?
And if the vector v in the collect_values loop had been deleted, why would I have a vector with 5 null cells and not the empty vector?

Comment: "the vector v in the collect_values loop had been deleted" you forget it is also return and the return value used to assign *v* in *main*

Comment: I don't understand, I put the "v" name in my hand, so? If it is returned, why do I have a problem ?

Comment: in `collect_values` the line `std::vector<int> v(next_to_last-first);` makes a vector<int> sized 5 with 0 in each element, then because 0*0 is still 0 the `for` does nothing in fact, so you return that vector and assign *v* in *main* with it. Whatever the fact it is or not *v* in both functions

Comment: do you wants that in an answer ?

Comment: Yes ! I want it

Comment: I enter my answer

Comment: Re: "at the end of the loop the vector ... will be deleted" -- no. It will be **destroyed**. But that's not the problem, because it gets copied into `v` before it gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in *collect_values*

> ```
> std::vector<int> v(next_to_last-first);
> ```

because `next_to_last-first`  values 5 you create a vector sized 5 where all the elements value 0

> ```
> v[i] = t(v[i]);
> ```

because *t* returns the square or its parameter but each element values 0 the vector is unchanged reassigning all the entries with 0

> ```
> return v;
> ```

returns that vector containing 5 times 0

In *main*

> ```
> v = collect_values(square,a,b);
> ```

*v* is assigned to that vector containing 5 times 0

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<b-a; i++) {
>     std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
> }
> ```

then prints 5 times 0 on a line

---

If you replace `v[i] = t(v[i]);` by `v[i] = t(i);` in *collect_values* you will print

```
0
1
4
9
16
```